# How to change Password column Field for Laravel 5.2 password reset

Tags: laravel

I have a project being developed in laravel 5.2, I currently am having troubles with the password reset to work. At the moment I have it looking for the correct email field and to let the user request a password reset email with link to reset it, then after the user clicks the link in the email the user will be presented with the form to change their password. When they submit their new password they are presented with this error:

QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'password_confirmation' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `all_user` where `user_email` = ...@hotmail.com and `password_confirmation` = 123456 limit 1)

I dont know why its checking in the sql statement for a field called password_confirmation. This error is getting caused by trying to get the user so it can perform the password reset. This is in the PasswordBroker.php file and the getUser function. More specifically the line $user = $this->users->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

My current code I modified so far:

ResetsPasswords.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Mail\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

trait ResetsPasswords
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Get the name of the guest middleware.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function guestMiddleware()
    {
        $guard = $this->getGuard();

        return $guard ? 'guest:'.$guard : 'guest';
    }

    /**
     * Display the form to request a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->showLinkRequestForm();
    }

    /**
     * Display the form to request a password reset link.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showLinkRequestForm()
    {
        if (property_exists($this, 'linkRequestView')) {
            return view($this->linkRequestView);
        }

        if (view()->exists('auth.passwords.email')) {
            return view('auth.passwords.email');
        }

        return view('auth.password');
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postEmail(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);
    }

    /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $request['user_email'] = $request['email'];
        $this->validateSendResetLinkEmail($request);

        $broker = $this->getBroker();

        $response = Password::broker($broker)->sendResetLink(
            $this->getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials($request),
            $this->resetEmailBuilder()
        );
        return dd($request);

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response);
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
            default:
                return $this->getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Validate the request of sending reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function validateSendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);
    }

    /**
     * Get the needed credentials for sending the reset link.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getSendResetLinkEmailCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('user_email');
    }

    /**
     * Get the Closure which is used to build the password reset email message.
     *
     * @return \Closure
     */
    protected function resetEmailBuilder()
    {
        return function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());
        };
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail subject line to be used for the reset link email.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getEmailSubject()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'subject') ? $this->subject : 'Your Password Reset Link';
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for after the reset link has been successfully sent.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function getSendResetLinkEmailSuccessResponse($response)
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for after the reset link could not be sent.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function getSendResetLinkEmailFailureResponse($response)
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function getReset(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        return $this->showResetForm($request, $token);
    }

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        if (is_null($token)) {
            return $this->getEmail();
        }

        $email = $request->input('email');

        if (property_exists($this, 'resetView')) {
            return view($this->resetView)->with(compact('token', 'email'));
        }

        if (view()->exists('auth.passwords.reset')) {
            return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(compact('token', 'email'));
        }

        return view('auth.reset')->with(compact('token', 'email'));
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function postReset(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->reset($request);
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $request['user_email'] = $request['email'];
        $request['user_password'] = $request['password'];
        $this->validate(
            $request,
            $this->getResetValidationRules(),
            $this->getResetValidationMessages(),
            $this->getResetValidationCustomAttributes()
        );

        $credentials = $this->getResetCredentials($request);

        $broker = $this->getBroker();
        //return dd($credentials);
        $response = Password::broker($broker)->reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
            return dd($password);
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        });
        //return dd($request);
        switch ($response) {
            case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return $this->getResetSuccessResponse($response);
            default:
                return $this->getResetFailureResponse($request, $response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getResetValidationRules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation messages.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getResetValidationMessages()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation custom attributes.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getResetValidationCustomAttributes()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getResetCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'user_email', 'user_password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $password
     * @return void
     */
    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->forceFill([
            'user_password' => bcrypt($password),
            'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
        ])->save();

        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($user);
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for after a successful password reset.
     *
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function getResetSuccessResponse($response)
    {
        return redirect($this->redirectPath())->with('status', trans($response));
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for after a failing password reset.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    protected function getResetFailureResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only('email'))
            ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getBroker()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'broker') ? $this->broker : null;
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    protected function getGuard()
    {
        return property_exists($this, 'guard') ? $this->guard : null;
    }
}
```

CanResetPassword.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Passwords;

trait CanResetPassword
{
    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reset links are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForPasswordReset()
    {
        return $this->user_email;
    }
}
```

PasswordBroker.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Passwords;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use UnexpectedValueException;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer as MailerContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker as PasswordBrokerContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class PasswordBroker implements PasswordBrokerContract
{
    /**
     * The password token repository.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\TokenRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $tokens;

    /**
     * The user provider implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * The mailer instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer
     */
    protected $mailer;

    /**
     * The view of the password reset link e-mail.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $emailView;

    /**
     * The custom password validator callback.
     *
     * @var \Closure
     */
    protected $passwordValidator;

    /**
     * Create a new password broker instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\TokenRepositoryInterface  $tokens
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider  $users
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer  $mailer
     * @param  string  $emailView
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(TokenRepositoryInterface $tokens,
                                UserProvider $users,
                                MailerContract $mailer,
                                $emailView)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->tokens = $tokens;
        $this->emailView = $emailView;
    }

    /**
     * Send a password reset link to a user.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
     * @return string
     */
    public function sendResetLink(array $credentials, Closure $callback = null)
    {
        // First we will check to see if we found a user at the given credentials and
        // if we did not we will redirect back to this current URI with a piece of
        // "flash" data in the session to indicate to the developers the errors.
        $user = $this->getUser($credentials);

        if (is_null($user)) {
            return static::INVALID_USER;
        }

        // Once we have the reset token, we are ready to send the message out to this
        // user with a link to reset their password. We will then redirect back to
        // the current URI having nothing set in the session to indicate errors.
        //return dd($credentials);
        $token = $this->tokens->create($user);
        $this->emailResetLink($user, $token, $callback);

        return static::RESET_LINK_SENT;
    }

    /**
     * Send the password reset link via e-mail.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
     * @param  string  $token
     * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
     * @return int
     */
    public function emailResetLink(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token, Closure $callback = null)
    {
        // We will use the reminder view that was given to the broker to display the
        // password reminder e-mail. We'll pass a "token" variable into the views
        // so that it may be displayed for an user to click for password reset.
        $view = $this->emailView;

        return $this->mailer->send($view, compact('token', 'user'), function ($m) use ($user, $token, $callback) {
            $m->to($user->getEmailForPasswordReset());

            if (! is_null($callback)) {
                call_user_func($callback, $m, $user, $token);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reset the password for the given token.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function reset(array $credentials, Closure $callback)
    {
        // If the responses from the validate method is not a user instance, we will
        // assume that it is a redirect and simply return it from this method and
        // the user is properly redirected having an error message on the post.
        //return dd($credentials);
        $user = $this->validateReset($credentials);

        if (! $user instanceof CanResetPasswordContract) {
            return $user;
        }

        $pass = $credentials['user_password'];

        // Once we have called this callback, we will remove this token row from the
        // table and return the response from this callback so the user gets sent
        // to the destination given by the developers from the callback return.
        call_user_func($callback, $user, $pass);

        $this->tokens->delete($credentials['token']);

        return static::PASSWORD_RESET;
    }

    /**
     * Validate a password reset for the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword
     */
    protected function validateReset(array $credentials)
    {
        if (is_null($user = $this->getUser($credentials))) {
            return static::INVALID_USER;
        }

        if (! $this->validateNewPassword($credentials)) {
            return static::INVALID_PASSWORD;
        }

        if (! $this->tokens->exists($user, $credentials['token'])) {
            return static::INVALID_TOKEN;
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Set a custom password validator.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public function validator(Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->passwordValidator = $callback;
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the passwords match for the request.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateNewPassword(array $credentials)
    {
        list($password, $confirm) = [
            $credentials['user_password'],
            $credentials['password_confirmation'],
        ];

        if (isset($this->passwordValidator)) {
            return call_user_func(
                $this->passwordValidator, $credentials) && $password === $confirm;
        }

        return $this->validatePasswordWithDefaults($credentials);
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the passwords are valid for the request.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function validatePasswordWithDefaults(array $credentials)
    {
        list($password, $confirm) = [
            $credentials['user_password'],
            $credentials['password_confirmation'],
        ];

        return $password === $confirm && mb_strlen($password) >= 6;
    }

    /**
     * Get the user for the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword
     *
     * @throws \UnexpectedValueException
     */
    public function getUser(array $credentials)
    {
        $credentials = Arr::except($credentials, ['token']);
        //$credentials = Arr::except($credentials, ['password_confirmation']);
        //return dd($credentials);
        $user = $this->users->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);
        //return dd($credentials);
        //$credentials = $credentials['password_confirmation'];
        if ($user && ! $user instanceof CanResetPasswordContract) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('User must implement CanResetPassword interface.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new password reset token for the given user.
     *
     * @param  CanResetPasswordContract $user
     * @return string
     */
    public function createToken(CanResetPasswordContract $user)
    {
        return $this->tokens->create($user);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the given password reset token.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleteToken($token)
    {
        $this->tokens->delete($token);
    }

    /**
     * Validate the given password reset token.
     *
     * @param  CanResetPasswordContract $user
     * @param  string $token
     * @return bool
     */
    public function tokenExists(CanResetPasswordContract $user, $token)
    {
        return $this->tokens->exists($user, $token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset token repository implementation.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\TokenRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function getRepository()
    {
        return $this->tokens;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your getResetCredentials contains the password_confirmation field...

Comment: Yes the standard reset password originally had that in there to my belief, I have tried taking this out and when I do it gives me the error Password index not defined. Does this mean anything to anyone? In my opinion its looking for the password field and its thinking that the password field is the confirmation_password, if I change the user_Password back to password it tries to look for the password field instead inside the sql statement, but I want it to look for the user_password field. Any idea on how to make that happen?